# Why is Firebase Automatic Screen Reporting causing my iOS app to crash?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to write data to Firebase Database using basic write code. I am programming in Swift so I created the reference to the database and followed the official directions on Firebase's help page. When I run the app using the write command:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.childByAutoId().setValue(titleText)
}
```

The app crashed and gives me the error:

> Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist

I have already to tried to disable FirebaseScreenReporting but the app crashes and returns the error:

> Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged.

I wanted to be able to write the data stored in the variable "titleText" to Firebase but I am not able to even test that without the app running correctly. How can I get the app to run and dismiss this error correctly?

Comment: Those don't look like errors that would crash your app.

Comment: @DougStevenson I agree, that is why I am confused. Why is it terminating my app?

Comment: Careful how you access your vars. ref and self.ref could be two different things depending on where they appear within your code.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for letting me know. I actually encountered an issue using self.ref in my code so I changed it to just ref.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is not in Firebase Screen Reporting. The error can be found below all of that Firebase data. The actual error I was receiving was a key-coding compliant error for one of the text fields on that page.