# Facebook login user data in Authentication doesn’t show in firebase consoles

Tags: swift

Every time, when I use a Facebook account to log in the application is supposed to have identified email shows up on the Firebase console but it doesn’t work properly. Users can use their Facebook account to access the application, but the problem is my profile page always got a crash when I attempt to make that page shows email of the users up. but if I use an email account to log in it doesn’t have any problem the email that I used to sign up able to shows up normally.

I have done everything in this link but can’t fix this problem.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login

On the profile page, I use this code to call the email and user

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FacebookLogin
import FacebookCore
import FirebaseStorage

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var passTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var changeNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageProfile: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var alertButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    let imageUniqueName = UUID().uuidString
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        setUserDataToView(withFIRUser: user!)
        customizeNavBar()
        sideMenus()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProfileViewController.openGallery(tapGesture:)))
        imageProfile.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageProfile.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        imageProfile.drawAsCircle()

    }

    func setUserDataToView(withFIRUser user: User) {
        nameLabel.text = user.displayName
        emailLabel.text = "อีเมล์ : \(user.email!)"

    }
```

this is all code on my LoginViewController page

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FacebookLogin
import FacebookCore

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if error != nil {
            print("โปรดตรวจสอบใหม่อีกรอบ", error.localizedDescription)
        } else if result.isCancelled {
        } else {
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                ProgressHUD.showSuccess("ยินดีต้อนรับ")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Main", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        ProgressHUD.showSuccess("ออกจากระบบสำเร็จ")
    }
    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

    //Textfields pre-linked with IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet var emailTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var facebookButton: FBSDKLoginButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginButton.delegate = self
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    @IBAction func logInPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        //TODO: Log in the user
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextfield.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error != nil{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print(error!)
            }else{
                ProgressHUD.showSuccess("ยินดีต้อนรับ")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Main", sender: self)
            }


        }

    }


    @IBAction func onClickPassword(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.passwordTextfield.isSecureTextEntry == true {
            self.passwordTextfield.isSecureTextEntry = false
        }
        else {
            self.passwordTextfield.isSecureTextEntry = true

        }

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Main", sender: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIw3w.png)

Comment: Could you post the whole Code?

Comment: I have edit and put all of my code thank you.

Comment: could you tell me about the crash? So,I can help you.

Comment: When I login via Facebook this error was shows up after I try to access the chat room

2019-03-25 01:43:39.538653+0700 LadyBlossomThailand[56399:8153466]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist

LadyBlossomThailand[56399:8153324] Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug

Comment: here is solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54390340/why-is-firebase-automatic-screen-reporting-causing-my-ios-app-to-crash

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful advices! I’ve followed your instruction but I found that the problems might occur by other cases. I think the problems occur when user login via Facebook but users emails weren’t saved on the firebase, so when I attempted to command it to shows the user emails the error always occur. Now i'm not sure what i have to do on firebase or my app.